# How to print pdf silently which is opened by Adobe Reader

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Is there any setting for printing silently with Adobe Reader? I want to print pdf without print dialog box in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't... at least not with Adobe Reader.

First, Chrome no longer supports the Adobe Reader for displaying PDF so the PDF will either open in the built-in Chrome viewer or will download and open in Adobe Reader depending on your settings.

Second, the JavaScript methods to control printing from Adobe Reader are privileged functions that require user permission to execute.

You can get around these limitations but it requires that the recipient of the PDF establish trust with either a digital certificate that you sign the PDF with or trust your domain. But in all cases, the user must opt-in before printing will execute silently... so... it's not exactly silent.